# duplicating a complex mongoDB document without duplicating the _id

Tags: mongodb

I have a complex schema in my mongoDB

```
var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    content: {
        page: [
            {
                img: String,
                frame: [
                    {
                        cx: Number,
                        cy: Number,
                        scale: Number,
                        rotation: Number,
                        cropping: {
                            x: [Number],
                            y: [Number],
                            visible: Boolean,
                            color: String,
                            shape: String
                        },
                        transition: {
                            easing: String,
                            time: Number,
                            type: String
                        },
                        requireUserInput: Boolean
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    views: Number,
    name: String,
    genre: String,
    Description: String,
    hasBecomicsMode: Boolean,
    dateOfCreation: Date,
    published: Boolean
})
```

When it renders, an _id is added to every field like so:

```
book = {
    _creator: "some user ID",
    content: {
        page: [
            {
                _id : "an ID is automatically added",
                img: "a path",
                frame: [
                    {
                        _id: "an ID is automatically added",
                        cx: Number,
                        cy: Number,
                    //etc...
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
//etc...
}
```

This makes it impossible to copy the field "content" because _ids are clashing.

Is there a way to make something like this:

```
newBook = existingBook.removeIDs() //kinda thing...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the embedded schema, you can specify options as a second parameter where you can prevent documents from getting an `_id` created by Mongoose (parent documents will still have an `_id` created by MongoDB when inserted). Thus you can define your schemas as following:

```
var frameSchema = new Schema(
    {
        cx: Number,
        cy: Number,
        scale: Number,
        rotation: Number,
        cropping: {
            x: [Number],
            y: [Number],
            visible: Boolean,
            color: String,
            shape: String
        },
        transition: {
            easing: String,
            time: Number,
            type: String
        },
        requireUserInput: Boolean
    },
    { _id: false }
);

var pageSchema = new Schema(
    {
        img: String,
        frame: [frameSchema]
    },
    { _id: false }
);

var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    content: {
        page: [pageSchema]
    },
    views: Number,
    name: String,
    genre: String,
    Description: String,
    hasBecomicsMode: Boolean,
    dateOfCreation: Date,
    published: Boolean
})
```

For more details, refer to the **[documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id)**.